# How to check the consistency of specific variables from different IDs registered repeated times in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match, data.table

I would like to know how I can detect if different individuals captured repeated times have the same value in specific variables along the different measures.

Specifically, I have repeated measures of some individuals (column ID) with some values of different variables along time (e.g. sex, weight)

I would like to check that the individuals are assigned all time with the same sex, having as reference the last measure because the measure is the most reliable.

Later I would like to store every row or register that mismatch with the references in one dataframe.

```
ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3")
Sex <- c("m", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m")
Weight <- c(20, 15, 30, 22, 18, 32, 26, 21, 36)
Time <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
df <- data.frame (ID, Sex, Weight, Time)
df
```

To get that, I have selected the last register of each ID

```
library (data.table)
dt <- as.data.table (df)
dt_last_register <- dt [, .SD[c(.N)], by = ID]
dt_last_register
```

And now I would like to create a loop for each ID to select the registers that do not match, storing all these registers together in a new dataframe (e.g. df_no_match)

```
# Create the vector with the IDs
ID_vector <- unique (df$ID)
# Create the loop
for (i in 1:length(ID_vector) 
  x <- ID_vector [i]
  df_subset <- subset (df$ID==x) # Select only the registers of one individual
  ...
  ...
```

I don't know how to follow from this step, and check all registers of each individual. Do you know how to get it?

Finally, I would like to change the values of the variable sex from the register that haven't matched with the reference, and store all the database with the changes in a new dataframe. 
e.g df_final

```
ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3")
Sex <- c("f", "f", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "f", "m")
Weight <- c(20, 15, 30, 22, 18, 32, 26, 21, 36)
Time <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
df_final <- data.frame (ID, Sex, Weight, Time)
df_final
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on your goal, but it seems this will work. They key is just self-merging your `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

#get the gender of the final observation for each ID
df[df[,Sex[.N],by=ID], recent_Sex:=(i.V1), on="ID"]

#find if there are any mismatches by ID
df[,mismatch:=any(recent_Sex!=Sex), by=ID]

#overwrite erroneous genders
df[,Sex_new:=recent_Sex]
```

If you really want to separate the mismatched observations, just do

```
df_mismatches<-df[(mismatch)]
```

(note that the parentheses are necessary to force `[.data.table` to interpret `mismatch` as a logical vector, otherwise it expects `mismatch` to be a `data.table` to which we're merging `df`)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have a problem in the code that I don't know how to solve, the first part of your code:
 `df[df[,Sex[.N],by=ID], recent_Sex:=(i.V1), on="ID"]` 
gives me the next error: 
"_Error in `[.data.table`(df, df[, Sex[.N], by = ID], `:=`(recent_Sex, (i.V1)),  : unused argument (on = "ID")_".

Comment: @Ruben `on` is a new argument to `[.data.table` available in the development version; see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for installation instructions. basically, this argument allows unkeyed merges. if you'd rather stick with the CRAN version, simply wrap both tables in `setkey`.

Comment: @Ruben note that `on` is now in the latest CRAN version, updated this morning (1.9.6)

Answer (score 2):

```
library (data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
# last row for each ID
dt_last_register <- dt[, .SD[.N], keyby = ID]
dt_last_register
#    ID Sex Weight Time
# 1:  1   f     26    3
# 2:  2   f     21    3
# 3:  3   m     36    3

# are there >1 Sex for each ID?
dt_last_register[setDT(df)[,list(mismatch=length(unique(Sex))>1),keyby=ID]]
dt_last_register
#    ID Sex Weight Time mismatch
# 1:  1   f     26    3     TRUE
# 2:  2   f     21    3     TRUE
# 3:  3   m     36    3    FALSE

df[,c("Sex", "Weight"):= list(Sex[.N],Weight[.N]), by=ID]
df
#    ID Sex Weight Time
# 1:  1   f     26    1
# 2:  2   f     21    1
# 3:  3   m     36    1
# 4:  1   f     26    2
# 5:  2   f     21    2
# 6:  3   m     36    2
# 7:  1   f     26    3
# 8:  2   f     21    3
# 9:  3   m     36    3
```

Comment: When using data.table 1.9.5 you can replace `length(unique(` with `uniqueN(`. Also the `.SD[.N]` / `Sex[.N]` / `Weight[.N]` can be expressed using `tail(x, 1)` which is a little more user friendly.

Comment: I think this is wrong because OP didn't say anything about updating `Weight`; it's likely that his data is tracking individuals over time so `Weight` is not static. More minor points: `as.data.table` is being used incorrectly; `setDT` is always preferred as it avoids making copies, and you even do this later on in your code; also (and this is style as much as anything) `list` can be replaced with `.` in the development version and onwards.

Comment: @MichaelChirico  First of all, the first few lines merely reproduce OPs code, so clearly he does include `Weight`. This is also why I left `as.data.table(...)` in the code. Finally, answering a question using a feature of the development version when it is not necessary is ridiculous. On the other hand, if there is a *new* feature in the development version, and that is the only way to solve the problem, then it is appropriate, although in that case it is essential to show how one downloads the development version.

Comment: I was referring to your final line of code, `df[,c("Sex","Weight")...]`; this is clearly incorrect as can be noted from OP's `df_final`. Reproducing poor code only encourages bad habits, so `as.data.table` should have been redacted. And there is a difference between _necessary_ and _superior_; @jangorecki's indication to use `uniqueN` is such an example. To call pointing out a superior method "ridiculous" is brazen to say the least. Not using `.` is _not_ why I consider your answer to be wrong; as I stated that's a minor, more-or-less stylistic point.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The part of the code writtento modify the variable _sex_ in all registers based on the last observation is what I was looking for,  I have only to remove the part of the weight: `df[,c("Sex"):= list(Sex[.N]), by=ID]`.
However regarding the display of mismatches, I would like to have each register and not only a variable that inform if there are changes or not.
The result that I am looking for is: 
`ID <- c("1", "1", "2")`
`Sex <- c("m", "m", "m")`
`Weight <- c(20, 22, 18)`
`Time <- c(1, 2, 2)`
`df_mismatch <- data.frame (ID, Sex, Weight, Time)`
`df_mismatch`